# CA conditions during REINSTALL

Tags: wix, windows-installer, conditional-statements, reinstall

I have a custom action which must be executed if the spesial feature's action state is "install". Now I am using next condition:

```
(&ca_feature=3 AND NOT &ca_feature=2) OR (!ca_feature=3 AND PATCH) .
```

I want to execute it also in Modify Mode. When the feature is already installed and user do not want to delete it. I thaught to append `OR (REINSTALL><ca_feature OR REINSTALL=ALL)` to my condition string. but it seems not working.. I can't get how the MSI is working in some situations, that is my problem. but i also can't find the answer in the internet.
Please,tell me what i'am doing/understanding wrong?thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition looks correctly. The last part with `REINSTALL` would be true if your feature is to be reinstalled.

Although you can try to use `!ca_feature=3` instead of `REINSTALL><ca_feature`: that would run the CA when the feature is installed.

---

I think your condition could look this way:

```
(&ca_feature=3) OR (!ca_feature=3 AND NOT (REMOVE><ca_feature OR REMOVE=ALL))
```

It would run the CA when this feature is scheduled for install, or if it's installed and is not scheduled for remove.

This part `AND NOT &ca_feature=2` in the first parenthesis is redundant because `&ca_feature` cannot be equal to 2 if it's already equals 3.

---

Use MSI [verbose logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988.aspx) to better understand what's going on. Run your installation this way:

```
msiexec /i package.msi /l*vx log.txt
```

When a feature state changes or a property is modified, you'll see a message in the log. Then you'll be able to compare the actual values with your expectations. Use other operation switches instead of `/i` to run it in modify or remove mode.

Comment: thank you,Alexey.I'll try your condition later when i'll enable the change_mode in my installer.I just wonder: if feature state is Installed,and i don't change it's state in change_mode (if i just add a new one feature) what will be equal to the REINSTALL property.I guess that it will be like REINSTALL="NEWONEFEATURE".If so it is really better to use !FEATURE=3 as you said.Thanks a lot, I understand now :) And hello from Moscow )